# Submit values and redirect user from to external URL

Tags: 7, redirection, forms

What is the equivalence of:

```
   <form action="https://paypaad.bankpasargad.com/PaymentController" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="content" value='<?php echo $xml ?>' />
            <input type="hidden" name="sign" value="<?php echo $sign ?>" />
            <input type="submit" value="send" name="submit" />
   </form>
```

in Drupal 7 ?

I already use following code in my form submit handler, but it doesn't work:

```
function Chargingform_nameform_submit($form, &$form_state) 
   {
    $options = array();
    $options = array(
        'method' => 'POST',       
        'xml' => $form_state['values']['xml'],
        'sign' => $form_state['values']['sign'],
        'headers' => array('Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'),          
    );

   $url = 'https://paypaad.bankpasargad.com/PaymentController'; 
   $response = drupal_http_request($url, $options);
}
```

How I can submit XML, sign to URL and redirect user to that URL at the same time?

This is my code:

```
function Chargingform_nameform() {
    $xml = 'PHP Handbook30000130000This is good book.MySQL Handbook25000250000This is a good book too.';
    // Get sing
    $sign ='ewtnXYRWPSalHhna9hgO+Kc0W9Z8JBUeG1FkcKPvZL5w2s588c0/B9r';

    $form['xml'] = array(
       '#title' => t('xml'),
       '#type' =>'hidden',
       '#value'=>$xml,      
    );
    $form['sign'] = array(
       '#title' => t('sign'),
       '#type' =>'hidden',
       '#value'=>$sign,
    );   
    $form['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('submit'),
    );
    return $form;
}


function Chargingform_nameform_submit($form, &$form_state) {  
  $options = array();   
  $options = array(
    'method' => 'POST',       
    'xml' => $form_state['values']['xml'],
    'sign' => $form_state['values']['sign'],            
  );    
  $url = 'https//:url';    
  $response = drupal_http_request($url, $options);   
}
```

I don't know really how to manage it in JavaScript.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can generate form like that using [`'#type' => 'hidden'`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#hidden) form API fields, and using [`'#action'`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#action) on form itself.

If you want to submit values to Drupal and then redirect user to external site, you cannot do it directly. HTTP protocol does not allow you to send anything from your server to another "on behalf" of your user. The only way to do it is:

1. Get data from user
2. Save data, process it, do whatever you need
3. Generate form with `action` pointing to external service (usually payment gateway), and data required by it in hidden fields
4. Use JavaScript to make user's browser submit it.

If you are trying to do it using `drupal_http_request`, it's your server that starts payment procedure, not client's browser - certainly not what you want. And payment server will not allow switching procedure between different computers - it would be a security risk to allow that. If you could hand your session on payment server to your user, what would prevent attacker from doing the same (but with his bank account, not yours)? I know that's simplified explanation - for more details you may try to ask on [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Good idea to save data and submit saved data! but I'm not very familiar to JavaScript for handling the submit! Is there any way other than the JavaScript approach to suggest me? Thank you again

Comment: @john every big company I checked uses JS for that. Simply put, JS is the only way you can "simulate" user doing something in his browser. Everything else either works outside browser and thus cannot do it, or would be way more complicated than simple call to [`.submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/).

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to redirect a POST action. Even if you do, it is not easy or guaranteed to be stable.

If you want to do it, you will have to write custom code to issue a 307 redirect. It won't work with Drupal's redirect functions.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/99966